# WRL: Class not registered

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, wrl

In Visual Studio 2015 I have created a C# "Windows Runtime Component (Windows 8.1)", which I would like to use in my native Win32 C++ project. I have generated the necessary header files for my WinRT component using the tools "winmdidl" and "midlrt". But when I try to activate the corresponding interface in my Win32 C++ code using the Windows Runtime C++ Template Library (WRL), I get the HRESULT code 0x80040154 ("Class not registered").

**How can I register my Windows Runtime component?**

Win32 C++ code:

```
#include "WindowsRuntimeComponent1.h"
using namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent1;
...

RoInitializeWrapper initialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(initialize))
{
    return PrintError(__LINE__, initialize);
}

ComPtr<IClass1Class> o1;
HRESULT hr = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_WindowsRuntimeComponent1_Class1).Get(), &o1);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return PrintError(__LINE__, hr);  // returns 0x80040154 ("Class not registered")
}
```

I have tried the following without success:

- I have added the .winmd and .pri files of my WinRT component to my
  C++ project.
- I have added my WinRT project to the solution containing
  the Win32 C++ project and tried to add a reference to it (error: "A
  reference cannot be added because it is incompatible with this
  project").
- I have added a C++/CX #using directive for the .winmd file
  of my WinRT component to my Win32 C++ code.
- I have tried to add a registry key for my WinRT component to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRuntime\ActivatableClassId", but there I would have to specify a "DllPath" for a DLL I don't have (and even as an administrator I don't have the rights to add a key there).

I am using Windows 10.

Side note: I am trying to integrate a WinRT component with my Win32 appliction because I would like to use the Windows Runtime API "Windows.UI.Input.Inking" for handwriting recognition. I have tried to use that API in my Win32 C++ code directly (using WRL) but received the HRESULT code 0x80004002 ("No such interface supported").

Comment: WinRT classes are not registered, the OS looks in the package manifest for the component. If it cannot find the [matching `<extension>` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924767.aspx) then you get 0x80040154.

Comment: Does a Win32 application have a package manifest where an extension can be specified?